# Is there any classifier which is able to make decisions very fast?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, svm

Most classification algorithms are developed to improve the training speed. However, is there any classifier or algorithm focusing on the decision making speed(low computation complexity and simple realizable structure)? I can get enough training data，and endure the long training time.

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods which classify fast, you could more or less sort models by classification speed in a following way (first ones - the fastest, last- slowest)

1. Decision Tree (especially with limited depth)
2. Linear models (linear regression, logistic regression, linear svm, lda, ...) and Naive Bayes
3. Non-linear models based on explicit data transformation (Nystroem kernel approximation, RVFL, RBFNN, EEM), Kernel methods (such as kernel SVM) and shallow neural networks
4. Random Forest and other committees
5. Big Neural Networks (ie. CNN)
6. KNN with arbitrary distance

Obviously this list is not exhaustive, it just shows some general ideas.

One way of obtaining such model is to build a complex, slow model, then use it as a black box label generator to train a simplier model (but on potentialy infinite training set) - thus getting a fast classifier at the cost of very expensive training. There are many works showing that one can do that for example by training a shallow neural network on outputs of deep nn.

Answer (score 0):

In general classification speed should not be a problem. Some exceptions are algorithms which have a time complexity depending on the number of samples you have for training. One example is k-Nearest-Neighbors which has no training time, but for classification it needs to check all points (if implemented in a naive way). Other examples are all classifiers which work with kernels since they compute the kernel between the current sample and all training samples.

Many classifiers work with a scalar product of the features and a learned coefficient vector. These should be fast enough in almost all cases. Examples are: Logistic regression, linear SVM, perceptrons and many more. See **@lejlot**'s answer for a nice list.

If these are still too slow you might try to reduce the dimension of your feature space first and then try again (this also speeds up training time).

Btw, this question might not be suited for StackOverflow as it is quite broad and recommendation instead of problem oriented. Maybe try https://stats.stackexchange.com/ next time.

Answer (score -1):

I have a decision tree which is represented in the compressed form and which is at least 4 times faster than the actual tree in classifying an unseen instance.

Comment: This does not align with OPs query

Comment: I think you would have to share more details for this to be useful.